# WPF - Reference XAML element in XAML

Tags: xaml, reference

I've trawled the entire internet, every forum, every blog, ever, anywhere.  I now literally contain the internet... except this one last thing ;-).  Here's the problem: I have a WPF DataGrid that has a column defined thus:

```
 <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First name" Width="100" x:Name="colFirstName">
                        <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox x:Name="tbFirstName" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{DynamicResource errorTemplateYourDetailsGrid}">
                                    <TextBox.Text>
                                        <Binding Path="Firstname" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                                <val:RequiredValidationRule ErrorMessage="Invalid or missing first name" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"></val:RequiredValidationRule>
                                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        </Binding>
                                    </TextBox.Text>
                                </TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

As you can see I've defined a Validation template called errorTemplateYourDetailsGrid.

The page has a continue button that I want to disable until all the fields in this grid are valid:

```
 <Button x:Name="btnNext"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Continue" Command="{Binding YourDetailsNextCommand}" >
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button"  BasedOn="{StaticResource BtnContinue}">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=tbFirstName, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=tbSurname, Path=(Validation.HasError)}"    Value="false" />
                                      ...etc 
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
```

A colleague has got this sort of thing working fine with a straight form-based layout (not using a datagrid).  So I'm guessing I need some syntax that will reference the TextBox in the cell in the column in the DataGrid so that the Triggers fire.  Simply using ElementName isn't working.  The button stays disabled even though the validation template disappears as expected when you enter text into those fields.

I'm using MVVM so any code behind-based solution isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

The MVVM way of performing validations is using `INotifyDataErrorInfo` (or `IDataErrorInfo` if you're using .NET 4.0 or below), so you won't define validation logic in your XAML, but in your model and viewmodel classes.

Once you implement it, you'll have one central place to query for errors and you could bind your button's trigger to your viewmodel's `INotifyDataErrorInfo.HasErrors` property.

Answer (score 0):

Check these articles to see if they can help you find the data template elements:

[How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb613579.aspx)

[C#/WPF: Get Binding Path of an Element in a DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298274/c-wpf-get-binding-path-of-an-element-in-a-datatemplate)